# Why can't I use "r+" mode to create a new file in Python with open()

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the docs of the `open()` built-in function, the meaning of "+" is as follows:

> open a disk file for updating (reading and writing)

But when I use `open()` to create a new file with python 3.5 in windows 7, I got a `FileNotFoundError`.

```
tmp_file＝open(str(temp_path),'r+')
```

From the explanation of `open()` in the docs, wouldn't it create a new empty file if the file specified doesn't exist when using the `r+` mode?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/python-open-built-in-function-difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r

Comment: thanks a lot.very clear explanation.just understood: if the doc didin't say it will create, it just won't create, even if it's open for writing

Answer (score 1):

You can see the full documentation of the built-in open function [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).
[image: Short Description of the parameters]
So the **+** sign adds update functionality to an added parameter. It does not give you permission to create a new file. That is why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

`r+` mode will open an **existing** file for write, but will not create the file if it doesn't exists.

You should open the file with `w` if you want to create a new file.

Answer (score 0):

You should use :
file  = open(str(temp_path), 'w+')

Comment: This is helpful, but it doesn't answer the question of _why_.